# "if" is not just sugar for "match"

Tags: coq

What is the difference between these two definitions:

```
Definition f : forall x:bool, if x then bool else nat :=
  fun x => match x with
           | true => true
           | false => 42
           end.
(* ^ Accepted by Coq *)

Definition g : forall x:bool, if x then bool else nat :=
  fun x => if x then true else 42.
(* ^ REJECTED *)
```

Before, I assumed that `if` is literally sugar for `match` but it seems that it is more restrictive when it comes to dependent pattern-matching, even though it also supports the `return` syntax anyway.

Is this intentional, and if so, what is the rule?

Comment: Is this issue [#7509](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7509)?

Comment: It is! Thanks for the link (and for reporting it a year in advance!)

Comment: No problem :) There is also a related issue with SSReflect -- [#8816](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/8816)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me: if you ask Coq to print `f`, it shows the `match` as an `if`.

```
f = 
fun x : bool =>
if x as x0 return (if x0 then bool else nat) then true else 42
     : forall x : bool, if x then bool else nat

f is not universe polymorphic
Argument scope is [bool_scope]
```

Comment: Indeed that seems like the most reasonable explanation! I found this behavior so silly, I thought I might be missing something, but if not it will be reported as a bug tomorrow.